# SQL multiple tables - very slow

Tags: sql, database, db2-400

I am trying to fasten up a SQL Server report regarding the IBM OS/400 operating system for my sales department.

A colleague of mine (which left the company) did this report and used a ton of sub selects.

The report usually takes about 30 min to process and often just fails to be displayed. I already tried to cut out some tables/rows in hopes of fastening up the process without success (all is needed by the sales department).

It works over all relevant data (orders, customers, articles, our order at the manufacturer, the manufacturer and so on). Any ideas?

I can't index it, due to the OS/400 system; guess it would be a new programming task for our contractor which leads to costs.

Can I use some clever joins? or somehow reduce the amount of subselects?

Comment: Writing correct joins can help to increase the performance of query.

Comment: post your code..

Comment: As per the conversation under an answer, this needs SQL editing into it. Please do that promptly to try to prevent the question from being put on hold.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using 4 part names in your query?  That's probably your problem...

From SQL server...

-- Pull all rows from the table(s) back to MS SQL server and do the where locally on the MS SQL server
`select * from LINKEDSVR.MYIBMI.MYLIB.MYTBL where locnbr = '00335';`

-- Sends the statement to IBM i server for processing, only results are returned..
`select * from openquery(LINKEDSVR, 'select * from MYTBL where locnbr = ''00335''');`

Answer (score 0):

Try running the subselects first, sending the output of each to its own table.

Update statistics on the tables. Then run the rest of the SQL, replacing what were originally subselects with the tables created in the first step.

Treat multiple layers of nesting the same way: each layer is its own insert into another table.

I've found that query optimizers have a hard time with complex SQL. Breaking-out the subqueries into separate steps often resolves this.

Between runs my preference is to leave the data intact as a reference in case debugging is needed, then truncate the tables as the first step of a run.

### Responding to eraser's comments

Assuming your original query takes this general form:

```
select [columns] from 
(-- subquery
    select [columns] from TableA
) as Subquery
from TableB
where mainquery_where_clause
```

Re-write:

```
-- Create a table to handle results for your subquery:
Create Table A ;

-- Update the data distribution statistics:
update stats (TableA) ;

-- Now run the subquery:
insert into SubQTable select [columns] from TableA

-- Now run the re-written main query:
Select [columns]
from TableA, TableB
where TableA.joincol = TableB.joincol
and mainquery_where_clause ;
```

I noticed some syntax issues with the SQL you posted. Looks like something got left out. But the principle of my answer remains the same. Please note that applying my suggestion may not help, as there are potentially many variables to your scenario; you mentioned subqueries, so I chose to address that.

Halfer's suggestion is a great one: edit your original question, adding the SQL code, and putting it in the "{}" supplied by the text editing tool.

I strongly suggest that you obtain the [SQL execution plan](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_explain.html) and post the results.

Comment: hmm I am not that fluent with sql I guess
can you help me out here?
Might it help if I post the code so everyone knows what the problem is?

how can I run the subselects first if they are based on the tables (like customer and order and stuff)

Comment: sorry
had no other way :(

Comment: @eraser51: please delete those SQL comments and add the query _in a formatted block_ to your question.

Comment: @eraser51: where is that box? I cannot see it.